# Create a countdown timer from 2 different date and time

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have created a google sheet which consist of dates & time. What I want to do is to create a countdown timer from those 2 data.

Here's my spreadsheet setup.

Column A:1  11/01/2023 15:10:00 PM
Column B:1  11/01/2023 13:10:00 PM   - The date and time that will show is from Column A + 24hours.
Column C:1   Show a count down timer here the formula would be something like Column B:1-A:1 = countdown timer but using an arrayformula.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear how the difference of two datetime values would form a "countdown". If the two datetimes stay the same, their difference will also stay the same. Perhaps you should involve the _current_ moment in time in that calculation. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168701/edit) your question to clarify that.

Comment: Also insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data side-by-side with your manually entered desired results. You may further want to consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 1):

To count down from the current time to the deadlines in column `B1:B`, use this formula:

`=arrayformula( B1:B6 - now() )`

Format the result column as **Format > Number > Duration**.

| Column B | Formula result |
| --- | --- |
| 1/13/2023 0:00:00 | 13:21:56 |
| 1/13/2023 12:00:00 | 25:21:56 |
| 1/13/2023 13:00:00 | 26:21:56 |
| 1/14/2023 0:00:00 | 37:21:56 |
| 1/14/2023 12:00:00 | 49:21:56 |
| 1/14/2023 13:00:00 | 50:21:56 |